# not able to redirect HTTP to HTTPS using rewrite in htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ssl, https

I have tried url redirection of HTTP to HTTPS on my website by using several different solutions in .htaccess and none have worked.
  Well, actually it does work if I type in directly:

(only for example) http://mywebsite.com

into the browser address bar....but if I try to redirect the url any other way, it won't work. If I try the link to my page listed on Google http://mywebsite.com/ it will not redirect to https://www.mywebsite.com. I need it to redirect from HTTP to HTTPS if someone clicks the link to my page from a search engine.

So far I have tried:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

---

then I tried...

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

---

and then I tried...

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !443
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R,L]
```

---

None worked. What else should I try? (this website is being hosted on a web hosting service site that has uses an apache web server). Also, I have an SSL certificate for the page, if that makes any difference.

Comment: Is .htaccess even enabled? Try putting some garbage text on top and see if that generates 500 error?

Comment: .htaccess is enabled.

Comment: See what happens when you enter: `https://www.example.com/` in browser?

Comment: my website appears, except that because this SSL certificate is self signed (at this point in time) it gives me the usual 'this connection is untrusted, I understand the risks, make an exception?'

Comment: Does the URL remain `https://www.example.com/` in browser?

Comment: it appears as 'https://www.example.com'. I failed at making that appear as code like in your comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

**Tip:** Clear your browser cache or use a different browser to test.

Comment: this might take awhile, I decided to go ahead and purchase a reputable SSL certificate.

Comment: okay, now i finally got it to work after adding what you put. thanks!